# Saving multiple objects at once in parse.com

Tags: c#, asp.net, parse-platform

I am trying to save multiple objects at once in a ASP.NET project to Parse.com backend. I have tried to save it one by one but in some cases it returns me error in the middle of saving process. So some of my objects are being saved some are not. Here is the code I am using:

```
ParseObject gameScore
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows) //imagine here I am saving 1000 objects
{
      gameScore = new ParseObject("SALON");
      gameScore["NAME"] = "NAMETEMP";
      await gameScore.SaveAsync();
}
```

Comment: If you are saving one at a time, why are you using `await` and `SaveAsync`?

Comment: save async is the only method that I can use to save. shouldnt I wait the previous object before saving another?

Comment: Is there a non-async version of the method to work with? And I don't know if you want to wait for the result of each one before saving the next.

Comment: no there is no other way than async. actually without await, it also worked but the documentation uses all the time await and i guess it is safer way to prevent skipping some objects.

Comment: "returns me error"? What's the error?

Comment: Rather than make individual requests to save each object, use the saveAll method which will batch them.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than make individual requests to save each object, try using the saveAll method which will batch them:

```
List<ParseObject> scores = new List<ParseObject>();
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows) //imagine here I am saving 1000 objects
{
      gameScore = new ParseObject("SALON");
      gameScore["NAME"] = "NAMETEMP";
      scores.Add(gameScore);
}
await ParseObject.SaveAllAsync(scores);
```